# I am creating UML for an information system which is needed to help deal with the editing of the magazine

Tags: java, uml, software-design, use-case

I have been tasked to create one use case to cover the main functionality of the scenario below. So far the use case which I have come up with is create magazine issue and the actor is the Editor. However, I'm not sure about the part where the editor edits the advertisement and sends it to the processing centre and how to include that in the use case. Any advice on how I can go about doing correctly would be helpful or any improvements which can be made would be appreciated. I have attached what I have done so far as well as the case study.

[This is the case study which I am creating the UML for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iqXW.png)

[Use case created so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NscZc.png)

Comment: Please do not insert pictures with paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

There is much more process and behaviour described in the scenario text than is logical to represent in one Use Case. To me, this would be more usefully described as using many Use Cases and several actors.

Do you have a specific flow within the scenario that you want to model? For example, placing an advert, moderating an advert, sending to the print shop? All of these could be Use Cases on their own. You would do well weed out and narrow down more exactly. Remember that a Use Case needs to deliver something business-useful to the User or a Business that they represent and needs to have a clear and unambiguous objective.

Comment: yes what I was thinking of capturing is how the editor creates the magazine issue (create magazine issue) but im not to sure where to include the part about him editing the advertisement and sending it to the processing center would that part go within the steps of the use case or would it be a pre- condition?

Comment: Hey -- the bit that doesn't make sense to me is around the photographer and journalist providing content as part of the create issue Use Case. I would have thought that would already be done, each being a separate U/C themselves? It depends on what you mean by "Create Issue" I suppose. You might be talking about an overall Process to create an Issue -- but again that's probably a process involving many U/Cs.

Comment: yes thats what im trying to capture the complete process of creating a magazine issue but im not to sure if the steps which i have written down so far are correct in terms of the process of creating a magazine issue